# Equal C++ STL Container Contents Algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, containers

Does STL or Boost contain an algorithm for comparing *contents* of containers of different types. If not has anybody written such an algorithm. I would call it `equal_contents` or simply `equals`. This is useful when asserting that some algorithms return same contents for different input container types.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is [std::equal](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/equal.html) algorithm. You need to pass the iterators to this algorithm, the type of container does not matter.

Comment: One caveat: you need to check that the sizes match first; otherwise, `std::equal` might either give a false positive, or iterate past the end of one of them.

Comment: @Mike Seymour How is it possible with iterators??

Comment: @innochenti: Lets say you have one vector with size 3 and a set with size 2, and you use equal like this: `std::equal(v.begin(), v.end(), s.begin());`. In this case, `equal` will try to dereference `s.end()`.

Comment: C++14 has accounted for this 'caveat' with last2 argument  

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal

Comment: Also, there is `std::ranges::equal` since C++20